# When reconstructing file B from file A and a binary difference B-A, given that A and B-A are correct, do we still need to verify the integrity of B?

Tags: software-updates, data-integrity, diff, software-patches

In the context of a software update system, suppose we have the following:

- `a.tar`: an archive file containing an old version of an application
- `b-a.patch`: a file containing the binary difference of the old `a.tar` and the new `b.tar` (from `bsdiff`)

Both files are present on the same system, and the **authenticity** and **integrity** of *both* files have been verified using sha256 hashes from a trusted source.

If we now reconstruct `b.tar` from `a.tar` and `b-a.patch`, can we trust `b.tar` to be correct, or is it still necessary to verify the integrity of the result, e.g. by checking the file hash?

*In response to the comments:*

I would consider it *necessary* to verify the integrity of the result, if there is a "reasonable" probability, under normal operating conditions, that the reconstruction process (using `bsdiff`) could produce a corrupted file while exiting normally.

What is "reasonable?" Not sure. Let's say more than 1 in 100k?

As this concerns a software update system, the scenario we would like to protect against is inadvertently replacing a working application by a new version that has been corrupted during reconstruction.

Comment: Please define "necessary", in particular including the exact scenarios you are trying to protect against and with reference to the requirements for your system.

Comment: This depends on whether you distrust your patch mechanism. If you do that, you should check the file hash on the result. However, do you trust your hashing code? If not, you need to somehow verify that it hashed the files correctly. At the end of the day, you need to trust your system to do things as you programmed them to do, unless you can afford to run 3 independent implementations and do a voting to decide which results to accept. Of course, then you need to trust your voting implementation...

Comment: @PhilipKendall Good point. See updated question.

Comment: What threats are you worried about? e.g. this is under "normal operating" conditions, conditions where your hardware may be failing, conditions where your update procedure is being deliberately attacked by a skript kiddie, conditions where your update procedure is being deliberately attacked by a nation state actor etc? (Spoiler: in the last one, you're screwed)

Comment: @PhilipKendall I'm not worried about security threats, just normal operating conditions.

Comment: @Hans-MartinMosner Thanks, you're right. I trust the patch mechanism as much as I trust e.g. my OS's file copy mechanism. For this reason, I would expect the additional verification to be *un*necessary. However, being generally ignorant on the subject, I thought I'd better ask the experts.

Comment: I've experienced one case where such paranoid validation uncovered a problem – unrelated file system corruption due to use of faulty non-ECC memory. If you have reasonably high integrity requirements I'd just check the hash of file B for peace of mind, but generally this isn't needed and should be handled by other layers of the software stack.

Comment: Given all that, it seems to me your biggest risk is a bug in `bsdiff`. Is there a more than 1 in 10^5 chance of that? Without having done an audit of the code, I'd say "yes" - but you should of course do your own risk assessment.

Comment: @amon Thanks, that's exactly the kind of information I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key thing to consider is: How will you handle the situation when this unlikely scenario occurs?

If you just get and error and can regenerate b some other way, well the impact is going to be very low, you can skip the check.

If it means sending the wrong data to mars and your billion dollar robot exploding. then you should check right?

In your scenario, it seems like the error will be detected when the software fails to launch, and if it does then you can probably make the patch again and reinstall before any damage is done.

But maybe you are updating high frequency trading systems, or BIOS on remote devices or something where the cost of failure is high. Running a check to make sure seems like a sensible thing to do.

In either case the probability of the error doesn't really matter as much as whether you can handle, or have a plan to handle, the failure if it occurs.

Answer (score 1):

## release process

At a bare minimum,
you *must* produce `b.tar` from binary patches in CI/CD
and automatically verify that its hash matched the desired hash.

This mitigates the risk of seldom-triggered bugs in your tool chain
producing a bad output file.
For example a rare buffer size alignment could tickle OBOB bugs.
Or an unusually large number of zeros could have some interesting
interaction with compression.
The bsdiff code is less widely used than NIST hashing libraries,
so is less well tested.
There is some interesting level of complexity to its internal
branching and datastructures.

mitigation strategy: Release process is halted until bug is diagnosed and fixed.

## deployment process

Things went well in the development lab, but they might not in the field.

Your tool chain may depend on dynamic linking to glibc and other core libraries,
which independently rev in the field in ways which differ from what happens
in your lab.

OS versions change, again in ways that differ between lab and field.

Well meaning sysads and OS vendors may arrange for surprising behavior
of fundamental primitives, usually in the name of security.
So for example an Anti Virus checker may intervene when it sees
you writing a byte sequence that matches some signature,
and decides to neutralize a perceived threat by altering write() behavior.

As product software grows, it may now exceed filesystem (or other) limits that
it previously fit within, leading to modified output.

It's hard to say what may possibly happen in the field.
Why do we ship production code with `assert`s enabled?
Because we want to learn of surprising field behavior so we can fix our code.
Same reason it's worth routinely verifying the `b.tar` hash at deployment time.

mitigation strategy 1: A background thread immediately starts verifying `b.tar` as it is being written, and asynchronously reports its completion status. It could report to local human operator and/or to the software vendor's webserver. This report could happen during or even after a software install attempt in a foreground process, and it might modify the installation. Total install time is not much impacted.

mitigation strategy 2: Foreground installer sequentially (1.) patches, (2.) verifies `b.tar`, (3.) proceeds with normal install on successful validation. Total install time is lengthened by time it takes to read and hash the archive file. Notice that sequential reads can be very fast, and multiple cores can be simultaneously hashing multiple stripes of the archive. Rather than producing a single golden hash, you may wish to publish one hash per archive chunk. Or publish single hash of several chunk hashes.